# How to query/curl for Parse installation without objectId

Tags: ios, terminal, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Say I need to get a particular installation from Parse. I don't have the objectId. How might I query for it? It's concerning iOS push notifications. I already have the deviceId. What is the curl command for that?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#installations-querying

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send push to individual user then you need to add some additional info to the installation object for example when the user sign in. So other users can query instalations to find a specific ones. I've done it like this:

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"client"] = [KZClient currentClient];
installation[@"phone"] = [KZClient currentClient].phoneNumber;
[installation saveInBackground];
```

And other user can find this installation object by querying like this:

```
PFUser *friend = [some method to get friend ...];
PFQuery *installationQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[installationQuery whereKey:@"client" equalTo:friend];
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:installationQuery];
[push setMessage:@"Test message"];
[push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
}];
```